# python pycurl equivalent of curl -b get command

Tags: python, http, curl, pycurl

How to convert a curl get command to equivalent pycurl command, specifically for the command :

```
curl -b "email=EMAIL; password=PASS" https://storkcloud.org/api/stork/ls?uri=ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/
```

Comment: Not really the answer you want, but kinda neat: https://shibukawa.github.io/curl_as_dsl/

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work for the `-b` flag anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) module:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(
    'https://storkcloud.org/api/stork/ls?uri=ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/',
    cookies=dict(email="EMAIL", password="PASS")
)
print r.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the pycurl equivalent but does the work, what you intend to do:
Try this(Tried and tested out):

```
import requests
import os
import json

if os.path.exists("input.json"):
        os.remove("input.json")

stmt = """curl -b "email=XXX; password=YYY\" https://storkcloud.org/api/stork/ls?uri=ftp://ftp.mozilla.org >> input.json"

returnValue = os.system(stmt)

with open("input.json") as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)

print json_data
```

Hope this answers your query.